# How do I add this entitlement in Xcode/Swift com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery?

Tags: swift, healthkit

Currently I have both the HealthKit and access to HealthKit records.

How do I add  com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery to entitlements in swift/Xcode?[image of current entitlement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nudqB.png)

capability for HealthKit is also turned on [healthkit capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWXkL.png)

Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: blah for blah contains entitlements that aren't in the entitlements file: com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery. To use these entitlements, add them to your entitlements file. Otherwise, remove unused entitlements from your provisioning profile.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Had the same warning.
Add a new key `com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery` to your entitlements file, use boolean type and set this to 1.

Apple Source: [com.apple.developer.healthkit.background-delivery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_healthkit_background-delivery)

Solved the issue for me.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6NLZ.png)